# Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection in r

Tags: r

I am new to programming.Currently doing R programming in coursera and got this error while doing assignment named "pollutantmean".I searched in forums and stackoverflow,but couldnt able to fix it.Appreciate your help.Thanks.

I got this error :

```
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") : cannot open file 'NA': No such file or directory
```

Note: I have a folder "specdata" which is the working directory.This "specdata" has all the 332 csv files.I want to calculate mean for one of the pollutant column named "pollutant" in those files and "directory" is the location of those files."id" is a integer vector mentioning the monitor number.so,here is my code:

```
 pollutantmean <- function(directory, pollutant, id = 1:332) {            

    files_full <- list.files(directory, full.names = TRUE) 

    dat <- data.frame()

    for (i in id) {
    dat <- rbind(dat, read.csv(files_full[i]))
    }

    mean(dat[, pollutant], na.rm = TRUE)
    }

    pollutantmean("specdata","sulfate",id = 1:10)
```

Comment: Hi Aruna, it looks like your list.files has created an empty string. You might want to add `pattern = "csv"` in your list.files call in case there are additional files in your directory.

Answer (score 0):

As per the error, it seems that list.files is returning empty vector for files names.

[list.files](http://astrostatistics.psu.edu/su07/R/html/base/html/list.files.html) returns only file nam inside the directory by default. So in that case, you should set the working directory first, so that read.csv will read the files inside the working directory.

```
setwd("<directory name>")
```

Now your function should work fine.

Comment: Hi Nishu,I got the 332 csv file names and the saved function "pollutantmean.R" from the list.files.But when i try to call the function using this code, pollutantmean("specdata","sulfate",id = 1) , above mentioned two errors occur.

Comment: I used this link as a guide for this assignment :                                                         http://xmuxiaomo.github.io/2015/06/10/R-Programming-Assignment-1/

Comment: yeah Aruna, thats obvious, you will get the above error because read.csv function is trying to read the files from working directory, and thats not the one which has 332 csv files. You need to set working directory to the csv folders.